# RPM spec decide which dependency installs first

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, zypper

I'm trying to create an RPM (`my-main-rpm`) that has over 10 dependencies (most of which are not made by me), but I want to first install another RPM (`my-rpm-prerequisite`) created by me. This `my-rpm-prerequisite` RPM creates/modifies some files that need to be done before the other dependencies install.

I want to be able to install the whole rpm using the single command: `dnf/yum/zypper install my-main-rpm` which should install all the dependencies. But I want that command to first install `my-rpm-prerequisite`

Is there any way I can do this?

Or is there some way I can execute a script before my dependencies are installed?

Comment: You can do some ordering with `Requires(pre)` but that's only when they're your own RPMs. You can't say "install me before `perl`" or something like that if you didn't package them all; that's just a free-for-all.

Comment: This is against the way RPMs are supposed to be written, which is why there's no real easy way to do it. Transactions are quasi-atomic; all promised files/RPMs will be there by the end. What is your end goal? What is that prereq RPM doing that is so important that it might affect RPMs that aren't yours, but not important enough to put into Kickstart / Puppet / etc?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to achive using `Requires` as Chris stated. But there is other way if you "only" want to execute some script.

First, you may specify in `my-rpm-prerequisite.spec`:

```
Supplements: rpm-prerequisite
```

This way default installations will install my-rpm-prerequisite as enhancement of rpm-prerequisite.

Second, you specify `%pretrans` script. It is run on very begining of transaction. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#pretrans

But be aware that %pretrans may be executed even when installing the base system. So there nothing installed on system (or in chroot). So it should be written in Lua, which is interpretted by rpm itself.

Comment: Wow nice hack, but you're in dangerous waters when you need to resolve to this kind of methods

Answer (score 0):

Afaik that is not possible. The `rpm` dependency system just makes sure that the dependencies for each package are installed, but not in which order. Your dependencies might already be present on the system before you run the installation of `my-main-rpm`. In that case it is impossible to make your script run before the installation of your dependencies since they are already installed.

The only way I see you can influence the order of installation is by setting dependencies, but you can only do that on packages you create yourself:

- If A depends on B and B depends on C, then they will be installed in the order C -> B -> A.
- if A depends on B and C, then B and C will be installed before A, but the order cannot be guaranteed; it can be C -> B -> A but also B -> C -> A.

Comment: I'll second this answer. And if there is dependency loop, then DNF can cut that loop in any place. In this situation, your dependency can be even installed after the main package. But... (I'll post this as an answer).